# Are there any unbalanced nuclear equations?

Tags: nuclear-physics

There are quite a few nuclear reactions/emissions.

Are there any that are unbalanced? With unaccounted for nucleons?

Comment: What would make them unaccounted for?

Answer (score 4):

#### Short version: No.

The search term you want is "baryon number violation", and the document you want for the most current consensus is the [Tests of Number Conservation Laws](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/ConservationLaws.action?node=CNXX&name=B&init=) table of the *[2015 Review of Particle Physics](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/contents_sports.html)* from the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov). You'll note that the branching fraction for all these reactions are given upper limits at the $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-8}$ level and the lifetimes for proton decay are limited to not less than $10^{29}$ years (more if you allow only the theoretically favored modes).

Comment: Good to hear my protons ain't a decaying.

Comment: @zeta-band Not yet, in any case.